# URL Rewrite Engine: Change pathname to php parameter

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this site that changes the page without realoding it, and, with **window.history.push** i made it change the url also.

But when I load the page with a folder after the domain name it goes to 404, obviously because there is no folders after the root. I tried the htaccess below but no success:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: -1 for absolutely inappropriate, unrelated tags - why did you choose them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^m/([^/]+)/?$ m.php?id=$1